# How to train for a competitive 10 km in two weeks?

Tags: technique, running

Good evening!

I've been running in an athletic club for two years. I've just noticed that I will have a 10 km run in two weeks (actually the 4th of June). I said two weeks to speak generally and make this question a guide for future athletes reading this post.

**I'm looking for training techniques and tips to prepare for the 10 km in two weeks, and, have the best postures and strategy on the day of the race.**

I'm doing 5 minutes 7 seconds for 1500m and did only two 10 km in competition.  I don't have the times for the 10km right now.

Comment: @studro hmmm, what should I do as far as I am very interested for a strategy to beat my opponents, should I edit and ask another question for the preparation on the Fitness SE? Strategies exist on such long distance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the time predictor from this site: http://www.runnersworld.co.uk/general/rws-race-time-predictor/1681.html

Based on your 1500m time I am getting 38:13 for the 10k.

1. You will not be able to improve your cardiovascular fitness much in time for the race
2. Focus on taking it easy for the week leading up to your race and concentrate on pacing
3. Aim for a small reverse slit, perhaps 19:33 for the first 5k and 18:40 for the second 5k
4. Good night sleep before race day. Have a light breakfast (banana or oatmeal, etc) several hours beforehand.

The time predictions about may not be accurate because 1500m is not very close to 10k (more accurate predictions can only be made from recent races of similar length). The point is not to go out too fast and pace yourself, which will allow you to pass a lot of people who tire more than you for the later part of the race.

Here is another calculator you can use to help decide on your intended pace for the race: https://www.mcmillanrunning.com/

Comment: Don't interval workouts have a relatively quick impact time? By taking it easy and focusing on pacing you mean shorter distance race pace runs for #2, right?